# Чтение бита из байта C#

Tags: c#, .net, консоль, byte

Есть задача прочитать из байта конкретный бит.  В качестве байта число 232DEC = 0xE8:HEX = 11101000:BIN

Создал метод расширения со сдвигом:

```
 public static class BitExtension
{
    public static bool ReadBit(this byte value, int bitNumber)
    {
        if (bitNumber < 0 || bitNumber > 7)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        var bit = (value & (1 << bitNumber - 1)) != 0;
        return bit;
    }
}
```

В основной программе делаю следующие действия:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte a = 0xE8;
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(a, 2));
        Console.WriteLine(a.ReadBit(3));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

На выводе получаю следующее:

> 11101000
>   false

Выходит, что у меня же 3, 5-7 биты установлены.
Если в метод передать 0x01 в качестве байта данных и 0 бит, то на выводе получим снова false, хотя бит установлен.

Comment: Скажите, а на какой вопрос вы бы хотели услышать ответ? (Я предполагаю, нужно найти ошибку)

Comment: @Вы уверены, что правильно используете приоритет операторов здесь: `(1 << bitNumber - 1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в коде. А именно в строке с проверкой самого бита. Нужно исправить эту строку на следующую:

```
var bit = (value & (1 << bitNumber)) != 0;
```

Разберем Ваш пример.

- value: `1110 1000`
- bitNumber: `3`
- `0000 0001 << 3 = 0000 1000` (здесь установлен бит #3, читаем справа налево, начиная с нуля)
- `0000 1000 & 1110 1000 = 0000 1000` (метод вернет true).

Прокомментирую код с вашей ошибкой:

```
var bit = (value & (1 << bitNumber - 1)) != 0;
```

Согласно приоритетам операций и скобкам, сначала выполнится `bitNumber - 1`. Все остальное идентично примеру выше. Таким образом, ваш код проверял бит в позиции на 1 меньше ожидаемой.

Comment: А почему слева направо?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов описка. Спасибо за замечание, исправил.

Comment: Благодарю за комментарии!

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемый, биты читаются справа налево, поэтому у вас не получается проверить представленный вами бит.

Вставляйте значение от 0 до 7, но считайте справа налево, а не наоборот.

Вот вам код для размышления:

```
public static class BitExtension
{
    public static bool ReadBit(this byte value, int bitNumber)
    {
        if (bitNumber < 0 || bitNumber > 7)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        return ((value >> bitNumber) & 1) != 0;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const byte readBitValue = 0xE8;
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(readBitValue, 2));

        IEnumerable<int> bytesNumber = Enumerable.Range(0, 8);

        foreach (int currentBitNumber in bytesNumber)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", readBitValue.ReadBit(currentBitNumber) ? 1 : 0);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

> Output:

```
11101000
00010111
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/KR7XhS)

Comment: ' var bit = ((value >> bitNumber) & 1) != 0;' Так наверное?

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу напишу, что, отнимая единицу от `bitNumber`, Вы сбиваете нумерацию. Если ввести `a.ReadBit(0)`, `(1 << bitNumber - 1)` в значении сдвига получит `-1`, что тоже является причиной ошибок.

В этом случае необходимо либо изменить проверку так:
`if (bitNumber < 0 || bitNumber > 7)`
, либо убрать `-1` в выражении, которое я привёл выше.

Таим образом, резюме:

1. Сделайте одну из предложенных мной поправок на выбор
2. Ведите отсчёт битов, начиная от младшего, т.е. "с конца"